# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in react js. Unable to pass data from parent to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Cart from './Cart.js';

function App() {
  const [count,setCount] = useState(0);

  return(
    <div>
      <h2>Pass data from Parent to child</h2>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <Cart props={count}/>
      <button onClick={()=> setCount(count+1)}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={()=> setCount(count-1)}>Decrement</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Cart.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Cart = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>This is a cart number: {props.count}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

I am unable to see the passed props from parent to child;

Comment: `<Cart props={count}/>` should be `<Cart count={count}/>`. React will send all the props as an object to the child, which in your case is the parameter `props`.

Comment: This is not how props is used in react. Please have a read of https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: This is javascript. And javascript has no relationship to java. Please remove the java tag for this question.